# Search Files inside Sub-folders in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Unlike the DriveApp.getFilesByType() method that will only search for files in the immediate folder, i'm trying to also search for files inside the sub-folders.

Found this [bloggpost](https://ctrlq.org/code/20034-search-drive-files) about it, and that works as is.
However my script needs to push the result into an Array. So far i can push files to the array but i'm not fetching the subfolder's files.

I have 3 functions:

**trigger_GetDriveFiles**

```
function trigger_GetDriveFiles(){
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B2XfBTL5aSGMZTNwTDlwT2JqNjg");
var filesJSObj = GetDriveFiles(folder);


   for(var i in filesJSObj){
    if(filesJSObj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
    Logger.log(bulkFile(i, filesJSObj[i]));
    } 
  }
}
```

**GetDriveFiles** (The out-commented section is where it fails)

```
function GetDriveFiles(folder) {
  var files = {};
  var fileIt = folder.getFiles();
  while (fileIt.hasNext()) {
    var f = fileIt.next();
    var owner = f.getOwner().getEmail();
    var id = f.getId();

    if (owner != "admin.fileshare@domain.com"){
      if (!files[owner]) {
        files[owner] = [];
      }

      // push the file to the owner's array
      files[owner].push(id);
    }

  }
  /*
  // Get all the sub-folders and iterate, This is the part not wokring!
  var folderIt = folder.getFolders();
  while(folderIt.hasNext()) {
    fs = GetDriveFiles(folderIt.next());
    for (var i = 0; i < fs.length; i++) {
      files.push(fs[i].id) 
    }
  }*/
  return files;
}
```

**bulkFile**

```
function bulkFile(ownerEmail, fileIds) {
  var ts = tokenService(ownerEmail);
  LibDrive.Init(ts);
  var dSA = LibDrive.ServiceAccount(ownerEmail);
 return dSA.batchPermissionChange(fileIds, "admin.fileshare@domain.com"); //<-- This is the user that recieves the folder/file
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in inconsistent data structures. The commented part of code treats `files` as an array, using `files.push`. In the rest of the code it's an object with keys being owner emails.

Another problem with `files` being such an object is that the function would have to merge object properties, which is [messy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/171251). I suggest changing the structure to `files` being an array of objects `{id: id, file: file}`. This is easy to concatenate, and after the work is done, the resulting array can be then converted to an object with keys being owners. I include the conversion bit `convertToObj` at the end.

```
function trigger_GetDriveFiles() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('your_id');
  Logger.log(convertToObj(GetDriveFiles(folder)));
}

function GetDriveFiles(folder) {
  var files = [];
  var fileIt = folder.getFiles();
  while (fileIt.hasNext()) {
    var f = fileIt.next();
    var owner = f.getOwner().getEmail();
    var id = f.getId();
    if (owner != "admin.fileshare@domain.com"){
      files.push({'id': id, 'owner': owner});
    }
  }
  var folderIt = folder.getFolders();
  while (folderIt.hasNext()) {
    files = files.concat(GetDriveFiles(folderIt.next()));
  }
  return files;
}
```

The function convertToObj has nothing to do with Google Drive; it's just a manipulation with JS objects and arrays.

```
function convertToObj(files) {
  var filesObj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var owner = files[i].owner;
    if (!filesObj[owner]) {
      filesObj[owner] = [];
    }
    filesObj[owner].push(files[i].id);
  }
  return filesObj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, i included the batch/bulk function just to show that the approach you are suggesting isn't working, due to i need to pass it on like this "function bulkFile(ownerEmail, fileIds) ".

Comment: The output looks like this now: [{owner=adam.aden@domain.com, id=1aYF62ynb8BYut7mbfrVFHC2GYfxhM0W8}, {owner=adam.aden@domain.com, id=1C5xhapMROPb3FZoSTRzcafDyZxYUWGpnh0}, {owner=adam.aden@domain.com, id=1UgGC9u2xxPlhbEQ4G1UIz1ktJxdDPqbzOvo}].

Comment: I wrote that the output can be converted from the array format to object format that you want. And now I included the function `convertToObj` that does that.